# Roboguice Not Working in JUnit Testing

Tags: android, unit-testing, junit, guice, roboguice

I am trying to write some tests with classes that use roboguice. Unfortunately it seems that guice is not injecting anything at all.

My setup is like so...

- I am using Intellij
- I have 2 intellij modules (1 for code, 1 for tests)
- I have 2 seperate module classes that extends AbstractModule(roboguice class) that define the bindings
- I have 2 roboguice.xml files that point to the package like this...

> ```
>     <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
>          <resources>
>              <string-array name="roboguice_modules">
>                 <item>com.evertaletest</item>
>              </string-array>
>          </resources>
> ```

Does this setup seems correct? Any class that is injected is null at the moment

Answer (score 1):

I believe the `<item>` entry needs to give the name of your module class, not simply the package.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
  <string-array name="roboguice_modules">
    <item>com.evertaletest.YourModuleForCode</item>
  </string-array>
</resources>
```

But that will only be relevant for your production code.  For tests, you will have to set your module in code instead of using XML.

In your test setup:

```
RoboGuice.setBaseApplicationInjector(application, 
    RoboGuice.DEFAULT_STAGE, new YourModuleForTest());
```